# How does fcron know whether the job was run?

Tags: cron, scheduling

I recently migrated from vixie-cron to fcron, on my laptop. How does fcron knows if a particular job was run in given period of time?

As a file can change during running, what constitute a different job? If I change, for example, from running daily to weekly, will it be re-run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During initialization (and at any time a user runs fcrontab -z), fcron loads and compiles the fcrontabs. Fcron then computes the time before the next job execution and sleeps for that time.

The time remaining until next execution is saved each time the system is stopped.

Comment: What about changes in fcrontab?